# Retrieve Complicated SQL Query from C#

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0, dynamics-crm-2011, crm

I've a complicated SQL query. I have to retrieve that from C#. What is the best method to retrieve complicated SQL queries? (Like QueryByAttribute, FetchXML, QueryExpression etc.) 
Here is my code:

```
SELECT R.Name
FROM   role R 
WHERE  R.roleid IN 
    (SELECT roleid 
     FROM   systemuserroles SR 
     WHERE  SR.systemuserid IN 
         (SELECT S.systemuserid 
          FROM  systemuser S 
          WHERE S.new_departmentid3 = 
              (SELECT new_departmentid3 
               FROM systemuser S 
               WHERE S.systemuserid = '8B8825F9-6B27-E411-8BA9-000C29E0C100')))
```

Thanks for the replies.

Comment: I'm probably missing something basic, but it looks like your query is overly complicated. Wouldn't this return the same thing: `SELECT R.Name FROM role R INNER JOIN systemuserroles SR ON R.roleid = SR.roleid WHERE SR.systemuserid = '8B8825F9-6B27-E411-8BA9-000C29E0C100'`

Comment: Nope. It returns only 1 row. Original one returns 6 rows.

Comment: the query returns all the roles of the systemusers that has the same departmentid3 as that systemuser Guid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using an on-premise system I would use the Filtered Views and create a SQL query against them directly. This is by far the best performing option and is fully supported.

If this isn't an option because you are using CRM Online then FetchXML will give you the best performance available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to disagree with Ben on a few issues:

The Filtered View contains security checks within them, and are designed to be able to run reports for users (they are not technically supported, but I have had only one breaking change over the course of 12 rollups, and it was realtively minor).  The Non-Filtered Views are nearly identical, except that they don't contain all of the extra joins to ensure the user has access to query the information they are attempting to.    So in this aspect, **the Non-Filtered Views are going to give you the best possible performance**, but I would recommend **only using it when it makes a big performance difference, and only for reports.** (Theoretically you could go directly to the Tables, but this is seems much more likely to be changed by Microsoft with any given Roll Up).

The best possible performance for large data requests available for online is not Fetch-Xml, but actually Odata since the payload is much smaller with O-Data than the Fetch Xml.  However there are some technical limitations to using oData (You wouldn't be able to do your current query in one call due to it having too many joins, but you could do it in two).

P.S.  I think this is an easier to read equivalent SQL statement:

```
SELECT R.Name
FROM   role R 
INNER JOIN systemuserroles SR ON R.roleId = SR.roleId
INNER JOIN SystemUser S ON SR.systemuserid = S.systemuserid
INNER JOIN systemuser S2 ON S.new_departmentid3 = S2.new_departmentid3
WHERE  S2.systemuserid = '8B8825F9-6B27-E411-8BA9-000C29E0C100'
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the use of the non-filtered views is not supported over use of the filtered ones. Yes they will work fine, are quicker and I very much doubt will get broken in updates but are not explitly supported by Microsoft. Also, due to the limitations that CRM imposes on the Odata endpoint is it possible to replicate the OP's query. I will admit that I have not used OData very much, but I would have thought that query would be impossible to do in one call?

Comment: @BenWilliams I stand corrected.  We use them currently for reports due to the enormous perform gain they have over the filtered:  http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/16462.microsoft-dynamics-crm-2011-and-microsoft-dynamics-crm-online-supported-and-un-supported-code-customizations-and-extensions.aspx

Comment: @BenWilliams the suggestion of OData is more for community education, rather than for use in this specific instance, because yes, in this instance, the query would require 2 Odata calls, and more than likely, the payload wouldn't make up for the time requirements of making the two calls.